# Cannot set user roles with enum on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOox3CGarf8) on how to implement JWT authentication on Spring, and it all worked well, that is, until I had to implement the very same `InitUsers.java` shown in the video.

The problem I'm getting is the following (inside `.role(Set.of(Role.ROLE_ADMIN, Role.ROLE_USER)` from `InitUsers.java`, which is shown further below):

```
Required type: Set<management.relation.Role>
Provided:      Set<[path].user.Role>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Role conforms to Role inference variable E has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Role lower bounds: Role
```

I'm not too well versed in Java, so I'm wondering how I can apply the necessary changes for the code to work, without breaking it and straying away from what is shown in the video.

The relevant implementations are below:
`InitUsers.java`

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import [path].user.JwtUser;
import [path].user.JwtUserService;
import [path].user.Role;

import java.util.Set;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InitUsers implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final JwtUserService jwtUserService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (jwtUserService.findJwtUserByEmail("emailaaaa@gmail.com").isEmpty()) {
            JwtUser u = jwtUserService.save(JwtUser.builder()
                    .username("Admin")
                    .email("emailaaaa@gmail.com")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("testpwd"))
                    .role(Set.of(Role.ROLE_ADMIN, Role.ROLE_USER))
                    .build());
            u.setEnabled(true);
            jwtUserService.save(u);
        }
        if (jwtUserService.findJwtUserByEmail("someemail@gmail.com").isEmpty()) {
            JwtUser u = jwtUserService.save(JwtUser.builder()
                    .username("Someone")
                    .email("someemail@gmail.com")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("123"))
                    .role(Set.of(Role.ROLE_USER))
                    .build());
            u.setEnabled(true);
            jwtUserService.save(u);
        }
    }
}
```

`Roles.java`

```java
public enum Role {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was tricked by IntelliJ's imports. In my `JwtUser` class, I had the following:

```java
@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 Set<Role> role = new HashSet<>();
```

The `Role` there was mistakenly imported from `javax.management.Role` or something of the like, and not my own implementation in the same package. This was a little frustrating but it serves as a nice lesson - remember to double check your imports!